# map of ints to class (template)

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I would like to write some class which maps int to something using templates.
What I'm thinking of are generally two options:

```
1. unsigned int ->  double          (scalar)
2. unsigned int ->  double[N]       (vector of length N; N is the same for each int)
```

I write a class around

```
template <class T>
class int2type_storage {
  public:
    ....
  private:
    typename std::map<unsigned int,T> map_;
}
```

With the first case, the usage is straightforward:

```
int2type_storage<double> map1;
```

The question is, what is the most efficient way/object for the second case?
I was thinking to do something like

```
 int2type_storage< std::vector<double> >
```

but I have a feeling that this will be sub-optimal. Another option is to store pointers

```
 int2type_storage< double* >
```

but then I have a problem that I should allocate memory for N elements outside of the map-class and take care to free it later.

EDIT1: Thank you guys for answering, I feel sorry that I can't mark two answers as correct.

EDIT2:

I have implemented everything, but my linker could not find functions:

```
undefined reference to `int2type_storage<std::tr1::array<double, 4ul> >::init(int, int)'
```

.h:

```
template <class T>
class int2type_storage {
public:
    int2type_storage() {};
    ~int2type_storage() {};

    void init(const int number, const int index);
        ...
private:
    int cur_index_;
    typename std::map<unsigned int, T>::iterator iterator_;
    typename std::vector<std::map<unsigned int,T> > map_vector_;
    bool zero_initialized;
};
```

.cpp:

```
template<class T>
void int2type_storage< T >::init(const int length, const int max_index) {
    map_vector_.resize(length);
}
```

usage:

```
int2type_storage< std::tr1::array<double, 4> > w_map_;
```

what's wrong?

Comment: I doubt you'll ever have to switch vectors to pointers in order to increase performance.

Comment: The only reason I would not use vectors is that they do not have size N. But I wouldn't worry about performance considerations before profiling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumming `N` is known at compile-time, you could use an `std::array<double,N>`:

```
int2type_storage< std::array<double, N> >
```

I am not sure what the reasons for the `int2type_storage` wrapper are, but you could also use a C++11 template typedef:

```
template <typename T, int N>
using int2type_storage = std::map<unsigned int, std::array<T,N>>;
```

Comment: the reason for wrapper are some more involved functions to get/set elements, find etc. Which are not relevant for the problem. I don't have C++11, I'm on Ubuntu and compile the code with mpic++. Compiler also complains about array not being a member of std (i included `<tr1/array>`)

Comment: @Denis then you should use `std::tr1::array` for the first part, but you cannot do the second (but it seems you don't need it anyway).

Comment: I'm trying to use your solution, but can't make it work. Can you have a look pls?

Comment: @Denis you have to implement the template code in a header, or a file included by a header. So put the `init` function definition in the header file.

Answer (score 3):

If you have C++11, `std::array` is the best, and there's also Boost.Array.

If you don't, then you can write something like:

```
template <size_t N>
struct Doubles {
    double data[N];
};
```

Then either directly use `.data` to access it, or add as many member functions and operator overloads as you want. If you add the right ones then eventually you'll have `std::array`.

The main sensible use for `double*` is if you are copying maps (or otherwise have multiple maps), and you want them to refer to the same data. But as you already know, it creates a resource-management problem, so you could consider `shared_array<double>`. You could also consider not sharing data.

There's also a possible special case, that in C++03 elements get copied into containers, whereas in C++11 there's a potential efficiency gain by moving them into the container in some circumstances. But arrays (including `std::array` and my class above) cannot efficiently be moved. If `N` is large, and there's a lot of copying going on, then *potentially* something that is efficiently movable might work better, so you could again consider `std::vector`.